# Find equal pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

> **Problem**
>
> Given an array A of unique integers, find the index of values that
>   satisfy A + B =C + D, where A,B,C & D are integers values in the
>   array. Find all combinations of quadruples.

I posted two versions of solutions and am wondering if there are any further smart ideas to make it run faster. I thought there might be some ideas which sort the list first, and leveraging sorting behavior, but I cannot figure out anything so far.

My code is \$O(n^2)\$ time complexity in the first version, where \$n\$ is the number of elements, and \$O(s^2)\$ in the second version, where \$s\$ is the max possible sum of elements.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_equal_pair1(numbers):
    sum_map = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(numbers)):
            sum_map[i+j].append((numbers[i], numbers[j]))

    result = []
    for v in sum_map.values():
        if len(v) > 1:
            result.append(v)
    return result

def find_equal_pair2(numbers):
    sum_upper_bound = max(numbers) * 2 - 1
    sum_lower_bonud = numbers[1] + numbers[2]
    numbers_set = set(numbers) # to make look-up existence O(1)
    sum_map = defaultdict(list)
    for s in range(sum_lower_bonud, sum_upper_bound + 1):
        for i in range(1, (s-1)//2 + 1):
            if i in numbers_set and s-i in numbers_set:
                sum_map[s].append((i, s-i))
    result = []
    for v in sum_map.values():
        if len(v) > 1:
            result.append(v)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print find_equal_pair1([1,2,3,4])
    print find_equal_pair2([1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: Tried golfing it?

Comment: @TrojanByAccident, what do you mean? More details?

Comment: "...wondering if there are any further smart ideas to make it run faster..." codegolfing it would make it faster, simply because of less code

Comment: I have the feeling that, in the first version, `sum_map[i+j].append((numbers[i], numbers[j]))` should be `sum_map[numbers[i]+numbers[j]].append((i, j))`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger, you are correct. Since I already posted code, I will leave there without edit. If you have any smarter ideas on my original question, it will be great.

Comment: @TrojanByAccident, I mean improvement for performance is more about improvement using smarter algorithm to improve time complexity. For codegolf, do you mean codegolf on stack exchange, or something else?

Comment: I mean making the code as short as possible.

Comment: @TrojanByAccident, got it and agree, if you have any thoughts on my original idea, appreciate to share.

Answer (score 4):

## Problem analysis

Since we know that each element in `numbers` is unique, we are guaranteed that \$s \gt n\$. So I wouldn't choose the second solution. It's even more obvious using `numbers = [1, 2, 10000, 10001]` where \$10002 = 10000 + 2 = 10001 + 1\$ will be found quickly by the first version but will take a long time with the second one.

Let's focus on the first version, then.

## Bug

First off, you swapped storage position for the sum of 2 elements and their indexes:

```
sum_map[i+j].append((numbers[i], numbers[j]))
```

Should be:

```
sum_map[numbers[i]+numbers[j]].append((i, j))
```

Next, the exercise ask for every combination of *quadruplets* but you are returning a list of *couples*. Meaning that you will have to kind of repeat the logic to perform combinations.

## Combinations

Whenever you need unique combinations of \$n\$ elements from an iterable, instead of using \$n\$ `for` loops on indexes, use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). It is both cleaner and faster (since it is implemented in C). It also easily handle cases where the iterable length is less than \$n\$.

Here you also need the indexes, so I suggest the following rewrite using `enumerate`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

def find_equal_pair(numbers):
    sum_map = defaultdict(list)
    for (index1, element1), (index2, element2) in combinations(enumerate(numbers), 2):
        sum_map[element1+element2].append((index1, index2))

    result = []
    for v in sum_map.values():
        for (a, b), (c, d) in combinations(v, 2):
            result.append((a, b, c, d))
    return result
```

You can also turn the results formatting into a listcomprehension:

```
    return [
        (a, b, c, d)
        for values in sum_map.values()
        for (a, b), (c, d) in combinations(values, 2)
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, love your comments, but your algorithm time complexity is still `O(n^2)`, do you have any ideas which time complexity less than `O(n^2)`? Not sure if sorting could help?

Comment: @LinMa Yes I didn't try to provide an algorithm with better complexity because I don't have one at hand. Computing the indexes of a quadruplet whose sums are equal to a target number can be done in O(n). However, we don't have a target sum and must figure out each combinations of indexes for each possible target sum, hence O(n2).

Comment: Sure Mathias, do you think my problem could be transferred to 23 sum problem? http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem